# Search a pattern from comma seperated parameters in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

My Parameter to a procedure lv_ip := 'MNS-GC%|CS,MIB-TE%|DC'

My cursor query should search for records that start with 'MNS-GC%' and 'MIB-TE%'.

```
Select id, date,program,program_start_date
from table_1
where program like 'MNS-GC%' or program LIKE 'MIB-TE%'
```

Please suggest ways to read it from the parameter and an alternative to LIKE.

Comment: Why are you passing a single double-delimited value? If you're stuck with that are there always exactly two sub-values separated by a comma; and do they both always have the extra pipe-delimited part that you want to ignore? And what's wrong with LIKE?

Comment: @Alex Poole Double delimited value is how the parameters are given . I would be using the extra pipe delimited value to calculate other columns. I want to keep the parameters dynamic instead of hard coding. In future 2 values might change to 3 or more.

Answer (score 2):

If you're stuck with that input and the structure is fixed, with each comma-separated element having a pipe-delimited value, you could possibly convert that string to a regular expression pattern, and then use `regexp_like` to pattern-match:

```
select id, date, program, program_start_date
from table_1
where regexp_like(
  program,
  '^(' || rtrim(regexp_replace(lv_ip, '%\|.*?(,|$)', '|'), '|') || ')')
```

With your example parameter, the

```
'^(' || rtrim(regexp_replace(lv_ip, '%\|.*?(,|$)', '|'), '|') || ')'
```

would generate the pattern

```
^(MNS-GC|MIB-TE)
```

i.e. looking for either of those strings at the start of the program value.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=26b619959b6c13c03aff690dfd36086e)

Alternatively you could split the input up yourself, with instr and substr, and - since the number of elements may vary - create a dynamic query using them. That might be faster than using regular expression, but might be harder to maintain.

---

> What would the regexp be to match CS|DC

It depends how you plan to use those values, but if you're looking for some column exactly matching one of them, then you could do something similar with:

```
'^(' || ltrim(regexp_replace(l_ip, '(^|,)[^|]*', null), '|') || ')$'
```

which with your input string would generate the pattern

```
^(CS|DC)$
```

But if you need to match the corresponding values as pairs - so the equivalent of something like:

```
where (program like 'MNS-GC%' and some_col = 'CS')
or (program like 'MIB-TE%' and some_col = 'DC')
```

... then you'd need to extract them as pairs, as @Gary_W has shown.

Comment: Thank you ! What would the regexp be to match CS|DC

Comment: @arsha - it depends how you want to use them - too long for a comment, I've updated my answer. But I suspect you want to treat them as pairs in your real query; if so then Gary's answer will be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention you want to preserve what's on the right side of the pipe, and want to be able to process parameters dynamically, here's a way to parse multi-delimited data that could give you some ideas using a CTE.

The table called 'tbl' just sets up your original data. tbl_comma contains that data split on the comma.  The final query splits that data into name/value pairs.

Hopefully this will help give you some ideas even though it's not the exact answer you are looking for.

```
COLUMN ID FORMAT a3
COLUMN PROGRAM FORMAT a10
COLUMN part2 FORMAT a6

-- Original data
WITH tbl(ID, DATA) AS (
  SELECT 1, 'MNS-GC%|CS,MIB-TE%|DC' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'MNS-GC%|CS,MIB-TE%|DC,MIB-TA%|AB,MIB-TB%|BC' FROM dual
),
tbl_comma(ID, CASE) AS (
SELECT ID,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1) CASE
FROM tbl
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL 
  AND PRIOR ID = ID
  AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL        
)  
--SELECT * FROM tbl_comma;         
-- Parse into name/value pairs
SELECT ID,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(CASE, '^(.*)\|.*', '\1') PROGRAM,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(CASE, '.*\|(.*)$', '\1') PART2
FROM tbl_comma;


 ID PROGRAM    PART2 
--- ---------- ------
  1 MNS-GC%    CS    
  1 MIB-TE%    DC    
  2 MNS-GC%    CS    
  2 MIB-TE%    DC    
  2 MIB-TA%    AB    
  2 MIB-TB%    BC    

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thank you ! I am going to incorporate part of your suggestion into my procedure.